# When a hand is copied and mirrored, the weight painting goes weird. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting

My first endeavor into the traitorous ocean of weight painting is a very simple glove-hand with pads on the fingers. After many struggles, I got one hand to work in an acceptable manner.

[image: The armature is in a good mood.]
In object mode, I duplicated the hand and cleared the parent. I then mirrored it by scaling it to -1 with the 3D cursor in the center. I Then applied the armature to the mirrored hand with automatic weights.

The problem arose when I tried posing the mirrored hand: the weight painting was all wrong, much different from what it had done on the other hand. I have tried many times to make sure it was not a fluke, but the results are still the same.
[image: This is nothing like what it did for the other, essentially identical mesh]

What is different about the copied hand that would make the auto-weight-painting treat it so differently, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Avoid scale (-1), don't rotate (we see a 180° in the first image). So apply scale, apply rotation... keep the mesh and armature, left/right along the X axis to benefit Blender symmetry function for the rig.

Comment: So the armature object can't be rotated when I apply it to the hand mesh? Also, what did you mean by applying scale and rotation? (Sorry, I do not know much Blender shorthand.)

Comment: Use "Ctrl + A" then choose "rotation and scale". This will keep things in place, but with scale and rotation set to zero. Again, the aim is to set left/right along the X axis...

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you could do that. I have applied the scale and rotation on both the hand and armature, but can you please elaborate on "setting left/right along the X axis"? I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Hold on, It's working now! Thank you very much for helping! :)